# Inequality with Pythagorean Triples

Tags: pythagorean-triples

When finding the Pythagorean triple for 
$a + b + c = 1000$,
with
$a < b < c$
and of course 
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$,
Wolfram alpha gives me 
$$
a < -500(\sqrt2 - 2)
$$
My question is where does this come from? Thanks!

Comment: I just answered this question, except the Wolfram part, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516450/pythagorean-triple-inequality/3278590#3278590). I think the Wolfram part comes from needing $a<b$. When the natural answer is $(375,200,425)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $c=1000-a-b$ into $a^2+b^2=c^2$ yields 
$$(1000-a)(1000-b)=500000.$$ 
That entails $1000-a>\sqrt{500000}$ , that is: 
$$a<1000(1-1/\sqrt2),$$ 
which is exactly the given inequality.