# Pythagorean Triple Inequality

Tags: pythagorean-triples

When finding the Pythagorean triple where $a+b+c=1000$,
Wolfram alpha shows me that $a< -500\left(\sqrt{2} - 2\right)$

When I input $a^2+b^2=c^2, a<b<c$ and $a+b+c=1000$

How does wolfram arrive at that inequality:

$a< -500\left(\sqrt{2} - 2\right)$

Here is the link: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%2Bb%2Bc%3D1000%2Ca%5E2%2Bb%5E2%3Dc%5E2%2C0%3Ca%3Cb%3Cc)

Comment: so what is your question? a link from wolfram alpha would likely be helpful as well

Comment: I'm guessing OP wants to know how to demonstrate $a < 500(2-\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Is the question "what is wolfram alpha thinking here" or is it "find such a  triple"?  No idea on the former.  For the latter, Hint:  start with the triple $(8,15,17)$.  If the question is "show that there is only one such triple", I think some programming is called for.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I messed up the post when I first posted. I had a different question.

Comment: @Brian Tung Correct

Comment: Oh, no worries.  I will leave my posted "solution" up because I am surprised at how efficient it is.  It's close to a pencil and paper solution.

Comment: OK, I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the inequality, we observe that since $b > a$, we must have

$$
c^2 = a^2+b^2 > 2a^2
$$

or

$$
c > a\sqrt{2}
$$

Thus

$$
1000 = a+b+c > a+a+a\sqrt{2} = a(2+\sqrt{2})
$$

or

$$
a < \frac{1000}{2+\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1000(2-\sqrt{2})}{2^2-(\sqrt{2})^2}
  = 500(2-\sqrt{2})
$$

As regards the original problem: Primitive Pythagorean triples can be obtained using the well-known schema

$$
a, b = u^2-v^2, 2uv
$$

in some order, with $u > v$ both integers, and

$$
c = u^2+v^2
$$

Note that in this case,

$$
a+b+c = 2u^2+2uv = 2u(u+v)
$$

In order for $ka+kb+kc = 1000$ for some integer $k$, we need $u(u+v) \mid 500$.  For example, with $u = 20, v = 5$, we obtain $a = 2uv = 200, b = u^2-v^2 = 375, c = u^2+v^2 = 425$.  Note that $a+b+c = 200+375+425 = 1000$, and $a^2+b^2 = 40000+140625 = 180625 = c^2$.

That this is the only solution can be demonstrated by noting first that $500 = 2^2 \times 5^3$, and observing that for $u$ and $u+v$, we need two disjoint subsets of factors whose separate products differ by less than a factor of $2$.*  This only happens for the above case with $20$ and $25$ (yielding $u = 20, v = 5$), and also with $4$ and $5$ (yielding $u = 4, v = 1$, and requiring us to scale the resulting triple by a factor of $25$).  Since these two pairs are in direct proportion to each other, they produce the same unique solution.

*ETA: Only if we require $a > 0$.  If $a$ can be less than $0$, then we only need disjoint factor subsets $u$ and $u+v$.

Comment: Thank you for this well explained answer, though I am more wondering about the inequality specifically

Comment: So I noticed.  I added it.

Comment: Awesome @Brian Tung. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm confused on your third step. You add a + a to one side, but only a + b to the other side, why is that?

Comment: Do you mean the $a+b+c > a+a+a\sqrt{2}$ step?  Let me break that up: We know that $b > a$, so $a+b+c > a+a+c$.  Then we know that $c > a\sqrt{2}$, so $a+a+c > a+a+a\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Ahh yes. That makes perfect sense now. Very well written answer! Thanks

Comment: A question on your last paragraph, Is there anywhere I can read about these ideas, I don't quite understand? Very interesting!

Comment: @TristanMcPherson: I'm not sure there's any specific idea to read about.  The point is that we need $u(u+v)$ to be a factor of $500$.  But $500 = 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5$.  How can we select two disjoint subsets of those five factors (not necessarily covering the entire set) such that the two subsets are unequal, but within a factor of two of each other?  There are only two such ways: $2 \times 2 \times 5$ and $5 \times 5$, and $2 \times 2$ and $5$.  Both yield the same ultimate solution: $200, 375, 425$.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain the part: factor of two of each other, mainly how $2 \times 2 \times 5$ and $5 \times 5$ only differ by less than a factor of two?

Comment: $2 \times 2 \times 5 = 20$, and $5 \times 5 = 25$; they differ by less than a factor of $2$; i.e., $25 < 2 \times 20$.

Comment: Ahhh okay, sorry for my ignorance! Thanks :)

Comment: How did you come about them being different by less than a factor of 2?

Comment: Because we need $u > v$ (otherwise, $u^2 - v^2 < 0$), so $u+v$ must be less than twice $u$.

Comment: Actually, I guess you never required $0 < a$.  If that condition is absent, then $u$ could be less than or equal to $v$.  For instance, $u = 5, v = 95$ yields $a = -9000, b = 950, c = 9050$, which has $a+b+c = 1000$ and $a^2+b^2 = c^2$, as required.

Answer (score 3):

Note:  seeing the edited form of the question, the following isn't really on point.  It addresses an efficient algorithm for finding the triple, it does not speak to whatever Wolfram Alpha might be doing.

Playing with the code, the following emerges:  Suppose $$a^2+b^2=c^2\;\;\;\&\;\;\;a+b+c=S$$
We remark that $S^2-2Sb=2a^2+2ac=2a(a+c)=2a(S-b)$  Whence:  $$a=\frac {S^2-2Sb}{2(S-b)}$$

Inelegant, perhaps, but it makes the computer search very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(A+B+C)=P=(m^2-n^2 )+2mn+(m^2+n^2 )=2m^2+2mn$

$$\text{We solve for  }\\ n=\frac{P-2m^2}{2m}\text{ where }\biggl\lceil\frac{\sqrt{P}}{2}\space\biggr\rceil\le m\le\biggl\lfloor\sqrt\frac{P}{2}\biggr\rfloor$$

Given $$P=1000\implies m_{min}=\biggl\lceil\frac{\sqrt{1000}}{2}\space\biggr\rceil=16, \quad m_{max}= \biggl\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{1000}{2}} \biggr\rfloor =22\\
\text{ and
 we test }16\le m\le 22 \quad \text{to see which yield }\quad
n \in\mathbb{N}$$

We find only one where $f(20,5)=(375,200,425)$. Note that $A$ and $B$ are reversible if $a<b<c$ is a concern. In any case it's a multiple: $25(15,8,17)$